# printout the length and words of the input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Sorry for my unclear questions, I want to input a single line text and print out the length of it, then printout the first word of it then the rest of the text.
Like if input "I am ruby", then the output would be:

```
9
I
 am ruby
```

How should I make it? I have searched for the questions and got some similar but doesn't help, The following code is what I make so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = kbd.next();
        String s1 = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner` doesn't have a `length()` method .

Comment: When you show code (as you almost always should), you should also tell what exceptions or errors you're getting. The above code won't even compile due to what @Arnaud says, so why did you leave that out? You're responsible for your homework, we only provide help. It doesn't work by dropping a pile of attempt here, and then we finish it up for you.

Comment: What's your desired input and output?

Comment: "Argument" is ambiguous. Whether it's a sentence or a single word or what? And then he wants to print the length of a word and then print the rest of it. Sample input and output would suffice.

Comment: Really sorry for my unclear question, I'm using Eclipse and it does show the error, what I want to get is that when a single line of input is given like "I Love You", and the output I want is the length of the input which is 10 and then followed by the first word of it which is I, and then followed by the rest of input which is " Love You".

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = kbd.next();
        String s1 = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s.length());
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Scanner does not have lenght(), Length() method is only for strings variables

Which IDE are you using (Eclipse, Netbeans, Intellij?) because the IDE usually shows you the error

Comment: What I used is Eclipse, and the error shows,  I have modified the question and still don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you want.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("1st string: ");
        String s = kbd.nextLine();
        System.out.print("2nd string: ");
        String s1 = kbd.nextLine();

        System.out.println(s.length()); // this is for the length
        System.out.println(s1); // this if for the input only
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've modified the question and could you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Still the same.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Word:");
        String s = kbd.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Input:" +s); // print the string
        System.out.println("Length:" + s.length()); // the length of the string
    }

}
```

[see the picture if its what u want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mWBa.png)

Comment: Thanks so much,  I found my question still unclear and modified again and I have got the answer, thank a lot Jam.